# InputElement width is returning an empty string

Tags: html, css, dart

I have an InputElement on my page, and I'm trying to access its width so that I can make other elements the same size.

My InputElement is top level, so I have:

```
InputElement nameBox = querySelector("#nameBox");
```

Later on in the `main()`, I have:

```
var width = querySelector("#nameBox").style.width;
```

After this line, `width` is always `""` instead of the expected `"149px"`. However, assigning to that `stlye.width` updates the width...

Any idea why this is? I understand that Dart's `main()` doesn't run until the DOM is loaded, so not sure why this isn't working.
By the way, the width is 149px by default--I haven't changed it.

Comment: This has nothing to do when main() is run. QuerySelector would return null if the element wasn't there (DOM not loaded).

Comment: I can reproduce in Dartium and Firefox.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.style.width` does not return the computed width but the width assigned to the `style` attribute of the element (`<input style="width:200px"/>`). If you want to get the real width you can use [Element.clientWidth](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_html/Element.html#clientWidth).

Comment: I actually discovered a way to solve this, came here to post it, and saw this answer was already posted. `Element.clientWidth` worked, I actually used `Element.scrollWidth`. The only issue with using these is that they are both final. So, I take either of those ints and convert them to a String and set `.style.width` to that.